# ivy error - The ngcc compiler has changed since the last ngcc build

Tags: angular

I get this error when i trying to compile with ivy :

```
ERROR in The ngcc compiler has changed since the last ngcc build.
Please completely remove `node_modules` and try again.
```

I tried to completely remove `node_modules` and reinstall, but the error remains

Answer (score 2):

In my case it is monorepo , repo with client, server and shared.

So remove node-modules in parent folder solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

The site that I created only 2 weeks ago in Angular 8, and refactored for Ivy compiler, gave that error today after doing ng updates on /cli and /core, on `npm start`. After some web searches, I decided not to delete node_modules in that project, but updated my global Angular/CLI, then created a new app with it and fully migrated my previous site. Which worked, it now serves and builds. My work is fairly simple but I do have lazy loading and router etc.

Here are some details:

`"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~8.0.1",
"@angular/common": "~8.0.1",
"@angular/compiler": "~8.0.1",
"@angular/core": "~8.0.1",
....
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.0.1",`

and tsconfig.json:

`,
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true,
  }`

Answer (score 0):

- Go to `node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/`
- There will be a lockfile  '**ngcc_lock_file**'
- Delete the lockfile and restart

Answer (score -1):

delete node_modules [all of your (current) modules in node_modules folder is not Ivy-compatible](https://medium.com/@sarunint/how-can-you-experimentally-try-angular-ivy-right-now-c23930062b4c)

> ng update --all --force

[image]

[image]